# How to execute ./distribute.sh -m 'pyjnius kivy' this command

Tags: kivy, buildozer, pyjnius

I am new in python . I installed pyjnius  using this http://pyjnius.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html  link on ubuntu but i am confuse about android installation how and where execute `./distribute.sh -m 'pyjnius kivy'` this command . please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, this documentation is well out of date, it refers to the long-replaced old python-for-android toolchain. I've now corrected it.

If you're building a Kivy app, pyjnius is installed in the APK automatically as a dependency of Kivy, so you don't have to do anything special beyond the [normal Android build documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html).